# index last character of a raw_input string

Tags: indexing, character, slice

I'm pretty desperate to get moving with my code and need help!

I am new to programming and have learned only recently how to slice.

I am practicing by writing my own code similar to pyg latin except instead of checking the first character, i need to check the last character  inputted as a string via raw_input.

I need to check the last character and I dont know how to index an unknown length string.

for example
word=raw_input("enter word:")
....the string "paper" is entered

I need my code to identify the last character of the string

I thought of only two solutions

1. write a bajillion if/elif statements based 
   if len(word)<4 and len(word)<6
   then i would index the last character as word[4] 
   this would give me the letter "r" in paper

this is however long and tedious and could be never ending unless i figure out how to write a code with count statements and I could do this once. but I'm new, like i said, and have a lot of difficulty using count statements as is...never mind something complicated

and

1. something like slicing word[2:] which would print out the characters second through the end
   except im looking for just the end
   is there anything like the function word[last_character]
   or word[end]??

I'd really appreciate anyone's help
I'm doing this for fun and just some practice getting the hang of programming.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Python or "in general"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Python, you can simply slice with a negative starting index to count from the end of the string, and if you just want the last character, just indexing at -1 will give you the last character;

```
a = 'paper'

print a[-1:]
>>> r

print a[-2:]
>>> er

print a[-1]
>>> r

print a[-2]
>>> e
```